# How to properly use svg icons with bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, performance, svg

I'm using bootstrap. Below the navbar I want to have a div like it is in the image, with the current path, and for the icons, I want to use bootstrap svg icons:

[image]

My doubt is how to properly use svg icons in the html and also how to style them. For example, the bootstrap svg for house icon is:

```
<svg class="bi bi-house-door-fill" width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="M6.5 10.995V14.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5H2a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5v-7a.5.5 0 0 1 .146-.354l6-6a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0l6 6a.5.5 0 0 1 .146.354v7a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5h-4a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5V11c0-.25-.25-.5-.5-.5H7c-.25 0-.5.25-.5.495z"/>
  <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M13 2.5V6l-2-2V2.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h1a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5z"/>
</svg>
```

And for the right arrow is this:

```
<svg class="bi bi-chevron-compact-right" width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M6.776 1.553a.5.5 0 0 1 .671.223l3 6a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .448l-3 6a.5.5 0 1 1-.894-.448L9.44 8 6.553 2.224a.5.5 0 0 1 .223-.671z"/>
</svg>
```

It's correct to use svg bootstrap icons like this in the html or there is another approach that is more correct? And also to style the svg is correct like in the example below using the class like ".svg"?

HTML

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-white shadow-sm">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="">
            Logo
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
                aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false"
                aria-label="{{ __('Toggle navigation') }}">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">

            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <!-- Authentication Links -->

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<div class="bg-light" style="">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12" style="">
                <ol class="breadcrumb mb-0" style="">
                    <li class="breadcrumb-item">
                        <a href="index.html">
                            <svg class="bi bi-house-door-fill svg" width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                <path d="M6.5 10.995V14.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5H2a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5v-7a.5.5 0 0 1 .146-.354l6-6a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0l6 6a.5.5 0 0 1 .146.354v7a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5h-4a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5V11c0-.25-.25-.5-.5-.5H7c-.25 0-.5.25-.5.495z"/>
                                <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M13 2.5V6l-2-2V2.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h1a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5z"/>
                            </svg>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <svg class="bi bi-chevron-compact-right svg" width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                        <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M6.776 1.553a.5.5 0 0 1 .671.223l3 6a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .448l-3 6a.5.5 0 1 1-.894-.448L9.44 8 6.553 2.224a.5.5 0 0 1 .223-.671z"/>
                    </svg>
                    <li class="breadcrumb-item">  <a href="#">Pages</a></li>
                    <svg class="bi bi-chevron-compact-right svg" width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                        <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M6.776 1.553a.5.5 0 0 1 .671.223l3 6a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .448l-3 6a.5.5 0 1 1-.894-.448L9.44 8 6.553 2.224a.5.5 0 0 1 .223-.671z"/>
                    </svg>
                    <li class="breadcrumb-item active">  <span>Subpage</span></li>
                </ol>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.breadcrumb{
    background: transparent;
}

.svg{
  color:gray;
}

.svg:hover{
  color:green;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

Comment: You should read the docs about usage [here](https://icons.getbootstrap.com/#usage). I think it answers all your questions. But yes, you can add the svg markup directly in the html.. or reference the svg as a separate .svg file with an `<img />` tag. Style it like any other HTML element... so you can add a css class or just target the tag directly -> `svg path { fill: #fff; }`. css class is probably better

Comment: Thanks, the approach in that link using the img tag seems more clean like: "<a href="index.html">
                            <img src="images/icons/chevron-right.svg" alt="" width="2em" height="2em" title="Bootstrap">
                        </a>". However, like that, the svg is not appearing, do you know what can be the issue? If I inspect the source code the image is there but I dont understand why doesnt appear on the page.

Comment: you set the width and height wrong. if you are setting them with attributes then it is a unitless value like this: `width="32"` not this `width="2em"`. Those attibute value are only in `px` I believe - see [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_width.asp). Else you can set the width and height in CSS